How can we promote the site on LinkedIn?
I'm not a big linkedin user, but I have noticed over the while that there are a number of psychology communities on the site.

What are the major psychology, and cognitive science communities on Linkedin?
What strategies might be effective in promoting the site to these communities?


Any ideas, anyone?
